# How to use computer while running pyautogui script on windows 10?

Tags: python-3.x, pyautogui

I have developed a python script which uses pyautogui to automate some stuff. So is it possible on windows 10 to run this script while using computer simultaneously?
I mean when script runs, it uses mouse and keyboard so it is not possible to use computer while script is running. so is it possible to do both simultaneously?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that !

Because you cannot use the mouse when it is controlled by your program.
You can use the keyboard but not the keys that presses by your program